# How does Alain Connes NCG compare phenomenologically with superstring theory?

Tags: string-theory, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model, non-commutative-geometry

In Veltmans book on QFT, *diagrammatica*, the full SM Lagrangian is published. There are more than a hundred terms and it looks pretty uninspiring and not quite the kind of equation one would want to print on a t-shirt.

According to Alain Connes in work done in collaboration with Ali Chemseddine, the **full SM** Lagrangian can be phenomenologically derived together with the experimentally verified extensions of neutrino mixing and the see-saw mechanism from a simple model in non-commutative geometry (NCG).

How does this *compare* with deriving the standard model from superstring theory?

Comment: There is no known, singular "derivation" of the Standard Model from superstring theory, no stringy model everyone would agree on to yield the SM (or even the MSSM). Therefore, the question is ill-posed - you can only compare things that exist.

Comment: @CuriousOne: That’s a cop out as far trying to get some kind of handle to account just how well String Theory is able to justify its claim as a fundamental theory.